# ADFS redirect makes MVC controller methods incapacitated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, controller, active-directory, adfs

I got an MVC Web Application.

There is the following controller for example:

```
    public class MyController
    {
        public MyController()
        { ... }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        { ... }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UpdateMethod(string parameter)
        { ... }
    }
```

**Now the following scenario occurs:**

A user opens the update form and put in values. He waits some time then he submits the form.

The method "UpdateMethod" should be called as **POST**. But because of the long waiting time the cookies or the session are expired and the ADFS is logging out the user, and then automatically logging in. After the log in the "UpdateMethod" is called (redirected by ADFS) again but now as **GET**. So the parameter values are lost and an error occurs, because of the non existent [HttpGet] for this method:

**"A public action method 'UpdateMethod​' was not found on controller"**

If I add an similar method with [HttpGet] I can handle this scenario. But I don't want to add for each Method a HttpGet.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void UpdateMethod()
    { ... }
```

So what is the best way to react to this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way:

1. Override HandleUnknownAction in the Controller
2. Check in the override if the Request.UrlReferrer is the adfs
3. If not, call base.HandleUnknownAction
4. It it is redirected by adfs (which acts like a session time out), do you own handling and show a custom error view